# laravel route for index page doesnt work but the route exists

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I've got the really bad error, I have a folder named "replies" in this directory "views/admin/comments/replies". and controller name "CommentRepliesController". the routes are defined like below:

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>'admin'], function(){
Route::resource('admin/users', 'AdminUsersController');
Route::resource('admin/posts', 'AdminPostsController');
Route::resource('admin/categories', 'AdminCategoriesController');
Route::resource('admin/photos','AdminPhotosController');

Route::resource('admin/comments', 'PostsCommentsController');

Route::resource('admin/comments/replies', 'CommentRepliesController');
Route::get('/admin', function (){
  return view('admin.index');
 });
 });
```

all my routes work fine except for replies when I try to go "mysite.com/admin/comments/replies, I get 404 page. when I change the directory to "views/admin/replies" and route to `Route::resource('admin/replies', 'CommentRepliesController');` the index link work perfectly.
my this route on my list is like below:

```
| GET|HEAD | admin/comments/replies | replies.index | 
App\Http\Controllers\CommentRepliesController@index | web,admin |
```

please help me understand this. best regards

Answer (score 1):

Your `resource('admin/comments')` routes are conflicting with the following `resource('admin/comments/replies')` routes.

One of the routes created for `admin/comments` will be for `admin/comments/{comment}` - that is the standard `show` route.

Now consider a request to `admin/comments/replies`.  The first route in your route file which matches that is the show route for comments above - the `{comment}` wildcard matches `replies`.

The order of the routes is important, so if you move your `admin/comments/replies` route *above* the `admin/comments` route, it should work.  Alternatively (and more simply), you should not "nest" resource routes like this, and use different prefixes.